# How to calculate time complexity of this loop?

Tags: time-complexity

```
for (let i = 0; i < n; i+=2){
  ...operation
}
```

I have tried various docs on time complexity. I didn't understand properly.

Answer (score 0):

The loop is simply incrementing in a linear fashion. If we use Big O notation, the time complexity for this would therefore be O(n)

Comment: So, it doesn't matters if the increament i with 2. It still stays O(n).

Comment: @MuzaffarShaikh How many iterations does your loop perform in terms of *n*? Then apply the definition of big-O.